# Sending array from PHP to Python and then parse in Python

Tags: php, python, arrays

I am having a hard time parsing an array in python when the array is coming from a php file.

test.php

```
    $count = 3;
    $before_json = array("qwe","wer","ert");
    print_r($before_json );

    $after_json = json_encode($before_json );
    echo $after_json;

    $command = escapeshellcmd("test.py $after_json $count");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
```

print_r($before_json ); will display - Array ( [0] => qwe [1] => wer [2] => ert )

echo $after_json; will display - ["qwe","wer","ert"]

py.test

```
    import sys
    after_json = sys.argv[1]
    count = sys.argv[2]
    print (device_id)
```

print (after_json) will print - [qwe,wer,ert]

print (after_json[1]) will print - q

How can I have it print out any of the 3 items that are in after_json?

Comment: You forgot to parse the json in Python. Import the `json` module, then you can use `json.loads(after_json)` to turn the JSON string into a list. **Update**: I felt this should be an answer rather than a comment, but I'll leave the comment since it already has some upvotes.

Comment: First make the python program do what you expect it do - you're just reading a string and outputting the first character from the string now .. and try to use a temporary file or pipes to send data between programs, and not the command line

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is the lack of parsing of JSON in Python, as stated by [rickdenhaan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866791/688161).

However you also want to make sure to quote your string correctly, when you send it to the shell interpreter in this line:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("test.py $after_json $count");
```

If we manually fill in the variables, we will get the following result (not sure what `$count` is, so I just assumed a value of 3):

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("test.py [\"qwe\",\"wer\",\"ert\"] 3");
```

This only works, because there are no spaces in the formatting of your JSON. As soon as you have spaces in the parsed JSON, your shell call of the Python script will totally fail. It's also a security nightmare, because each of the elements of the JSON array can lead to arbitrary code execution in your shell.

You have to escape your arguments when you pass them to the shell. For this, you should use the function `escapeshellarg`.

This is probably what you want to do instead:

```
$escaped_json = escapeshellarg($after_json)
$command = escapeshellcmd("test.py $escaped_json $count");
```

If you are not 100% sure that `$count` is an integer, you should also call `escapeshellarg` on that parameter.

Comment: Thanks folks. I made your changes but I am getting a blank output. $count is just a counter that I will use in the py script to loop. test.php is  
 $count = 3;
    $before_json = array("qwe","wer","ert");
    

    $after_json = json_encode($before_json );
    

    $escaped_json = escapeshellarg($after_json);
 $command = escapeshellcmd("python test.py $escaped_json $count");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;

and test.py is

import sys, json
escaped_json = sys.argv[1]
count = sys.argv[2]

parsed_data = json.loads(escaped_json)
print (parsed_data[0])

Comment: Also noticed that doing a simple print"test" after the line parsed_data = json.loads(escaped_json) will not print

Comment: If I do print escaped_json withon test.py, I get this \[\"qwe\",\"wer\",\"ert\"\]

Comment: I got it all working by writing to a file, stripping the [ and ] and then parsing the info. Thanks for everyones input

Answer (score 0):

You still need to parse the JSON string in Python. You can use the `json` module for that:

```
import sys, json
after_json = sys.argv[1]
count = sys.argv[2]

parsed_data = json.loads(after_json)
print (parsed_data[0])  # will print "qwe"
```

Answer (score 0):

`after_json=after_json[1:-1].split(",")`

while `after_json` is `["qwe","wer","ert"]` u can omit first and last character and then split remaining string wich can be split by comma

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the problem is and **how** the code helps.